# invalid JPEG format: missing SOI marker

Tags: image, go, jpeg

Trying to decode an image and write to a file.

This is my code:

```
package main

import (
        "bytes"
        "fmt"
        "github.com/reteps/gopowerschool"
        "image/jpeg"
)

func main() {
        client := gopowerschool.Client("https://example.com")
        session, userID, err := client.CreateUserSessionAndStudent("username", "password")
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }   
        response, err := client.GetStudentPhoto(&gopowerschool.GetStudentPhoto{UserSessionVO: session, StudentID: userID})
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }   
        fmt.Println(string(response.Return_))
        image, err := jpeg.Decode(bytes.NewReader(response.Return_))
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }   
        fmt.Println(image)

}
```

The image is:

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRg....VNpSP8f6VmE4oopks//Z
```

It is giving me an error when I try to decode the []byte of the image.

```
panic: invalid JPEG format: missing SOI marker
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Go, so does it need a base-64 decode in there for the base-64-encoded image?

Comment: it does. Under `xml_parser.go`, it returns a `[]byte`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton you might be right! How do you know it's base64 encoded?

Comment: @user7903682 I decoded ""/9j/4AAQSkZJRg==" and got "???? JFIF" and the "JFIF" gave it away.

Comment: that was it! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data for the image that you show appears to be base-64 encoded.

Base-64 decoding "/9j/4AAQSkZJRg==" (the "==" pads it to a correct length) gives "???? JFIF". The important hint is the "JFIF", which shows that the image data is indeed base-64 encoded.

To get the image, you need to base-64 decode the string that represents the image data.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue because I was using an Imgur link to the image **page** (e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAR7j.jpg), instead of the actual URL of the image (like https://i.imgur.com/VXM2I36.jpg).

Part of the problem is that the "Copy link" button on Imgur does not actually give a direct link to the image, as noted in [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/95898/48535).